# SSRS How to Concatenate Multiple Rows with Dynamic Columns

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Right now I have dynamic columns based off of a query, and then I have data attached to those columns that I want to populate in rows. They associate just fine, but the problem is that the rows hold whatever place they were in, instead of ascending to the top again, like so:

```
 |column|column2|column3|
 | row1 |       |       |
 |      | row2  |       |
 |      |       |  row3 |
```

And the goal is:

```
 |column|column2|column3|
 | row1 | row2  | row3  |
 |      |       |       |
 |      |       |       |
```

I know that I could do this in the query, combining the headers with a dynamic query, but is there any SSRS magic that can achieve this without that?

EDIT 1
I am using a matrix, sorry about not specifying, I heard that the only way to do dynamic columns are matrices, so I thought it was implied.

EDIT 2
The rows come in like

```
 Wanted_Column | Wanted Row
 Column        | data
 Column2       | data
 Column        | data
```

and I want it so that the table will look like

```
 |column|column2|
 | data | data  |
 | data |       |   
 |      |       |
```

for any number of columns/rows

Comment: I see the first example happen most frequently with `case` statements. Perhaps you need a `row_number()` function? We can't really tell unless you show us some table samples you're working with or code.

Comment: Added in everything that I have going into the report, minus the query that is just `select Wanted_Column, Wanted_Row From Table`

Comment: What type of data is `data`? A simple sample of your data would go a long way to helping you.

Comment: Data is a varchar, as is the column name.

Comment: Can you just please post a sample of your data and what you expect out. Will there be duplicates, if so how will these be handled? I'm assuming your data column doesn't actually all say 'data'......  people are willing to help but you really need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using a matrix to do this. It's not clear from your question... Anyway, you'll need to add row grouping. If you don't have data that can be grouped by an actual column value then set the group expression to `1` and that should do it.

If this is not correct then please show you data as it comes from the dataset and the expected output.

Comment: the sort on 1 will work, but only for the first of each piece of data.